# Connect with SSO on Experience Builder application deployed in Enterprise

Tags: arcgis-experience-builder

I try to develop my application in Experience Builder Developer.

I successfully deployed my application to my Portal but when I share the link to my colleagues, they can't access to my application.

I set the share parameter of the layer in the application to "Organization only" because we don't want to publish data.

So when they click on the link, a pop-up asks them to enter their username/password to access to the application. But we use SSO with our Windows session IDs. If we use it to log in and use the app, it doesn't work.

How can we configure all of this so that the login/password request is SSO?